# IntelliJ IDEA - How to reattach and place Console tab back to IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

Am new to IntelliJ IDEA (am using 2017.1.3)...

Accidentally, made my Console tab window float and can't seem to reattach it to IntelliJ IDEA. When I run the Debugger, it launches as a separate window (which is very annoying).

Is there a way to reattach it back to the main window but on right of the Projects view and right underneath the Source Editor view?

Attached is a screenshot of the issue, at hand (which one can click on to see it in high res):

[image]

**Update**

Okay, somehow (by doing a lot of clicking and dragging), this is the closest that I've come to what I've want. The thing that's bothersome is that I can only see the Console (stdout) updated when the debugging session is over (not in real-time, as I've would been able to do in Eclipse). :(

[image]

Comment: Use the Restore layout button in the debugger toolbar, then you can rearrange it inside Debugger tool window.

Comment: Thank you, I clicked on the Restore Layout button but now the Console Window has completely disappeared and I was relying on it to be in the main window so I can see log statements and stdout. I can't seem to find the Console window anywhere?

Comment: It's a tab in Debugger by default.

Comment: I see it now... Can I move it to the bottom of the Source Code Editor view? I want to be able to look at the Console while I debug.

Comment: No, you can move it only inside the debugger tool window.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, finally got it to where I wanted it but it doesn't update in real-time in stdout it only does that when the debugging session is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the console in realtime:
[image]

If you want all the JUnit test output to the console in real-time, just do as follows:

1. choose the configure

[image]

2. do configure for JUnit

[image]

Comment: This is good advice, thanks... But I wanted to use my own print statements and log statements for stdout - I can see the JUnit Test Messages from UI.

Comment: what do you mean your own print statement? I think if you check these option, anything output to stdout will be shown on Console in realtime.

Comment: cheer, I have tried System.out.print() and it works.

Comment: Yes, thank you it does work now! Woohoo! Unfortunately, that last screenshot, when I relaunched IntelliJ IDEA, it insdie the Debugger as Tab and not underneath. I'll keep hacking away.

Comment: According to my test, the location of the Console tab in Debug window can be remembered. You can also try the  Windows-> Store Current Layout as Default to save the layout of every window.

Comment: How do you find the list of memories?

Comment: list of memories? do you mean the stack in frames or the variables?

Comment: No, I misunderstood your question... Apparently, I initially thought you meant that the previous working version I had could be remembered and found by looking at a list with timestamps. You meant that I could store the layout as the default - which yes, I already saw this option earlier.

Comment: OK, what I mean is that: For all the location of windows in Jetbrain, you can use **Windows-> Store Current Layout as Default** to remember by IDE. and the location of Tab in Windows maybe auto remember by IDE automatically I think according to my experience.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help... I've learned a lot about IntelliJ IDEA in my first two days of exploration. I know there's a vast amount more power it has in terms of doing lots with a codebase.

Comment: try to use Jetbrain replace Eclipse and I think you will not regret it. :) hah

Answer (score 1):

[image]

floating separate tab of windows need restore on the tab.

[image]

You have two methods to restore floating windows:

1. uncheck the floating mode in the terminal windows

[image]

2. uncheck the floating mode in the Windows/Active Tool Windows
   [image]

Comment: Sorry, that is the Terminal, I meant the Console.

Comment: the second method I think can solve your issue. It is same thing for all windows of Jetbrain

Comment: OK I got your issue, wait a minutes

Comment: find the debug windows that the console belongs to. and click the restore button on the debug windows. Because this tab belongs to this windows.

Comment: If you read the comments that CrazyCoder did, then you'll see I already did this...

Comment: see the new image: Drag the console tab to the bottom of debug window,
Because this is tab of debug window, so you can only change the location of this tab in the Debug windows.

Comment: if you want to only see source code and console, you can restore the layout and switch the Console Tab. By the way, the tab can put any location in the Debug Windows, you can drag and hold it and try everywhere in Debug windows

Comment: Please see the newly updated original post... I have what I want now but it doesn't show the changes in Console (e.g. stdout) in real-time while I step through code. Disappointing because I could do that in Eclipse.

Comment: see this answer can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294171/2000468

Comment: By the way, I think the Jetbrain IDE is very powerful and very flexible. The method to learn to use it is JUST TRY every option! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me show the 4 location of Console in the Debug view, I think there should be one which is what you want:

1. first
   [image]
2. second
   [image]
3. third
   [image]
4. last
   [image]

Comment: Am getting close... I'll put an new screenshot inside my original post.

Comment: could you check the View -> Tool Windows -> Debug ? Whether it is enable?

Comment: Yes, its not gray (which means its there and enabled)... Please see my updated original post (I added a new screenshot).

Comment: OK that's a different question. let me give an solution for this issue with picture

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1, the configuration is added in to individual console as Settings.

In the top right of the required Tab, Tap on Settings icon -> View Mode -> Dock Pinned.
This will be the same steps for other tabs like 'Terminal', 'Services' etc.,